# How to mimic `UITableViewController` showing of the large titles in `navigationBar` on iOS 11

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios11

I'm trying to use `prefersLargeTitles` from iOS 11 in my application. It works as expected in subclasses of `UITableViewController`:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

However, in one case I needed to subclass `UIViewController` and add a table view myself. In this situation I needed to constraint the table to the view myself:

```
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.otherView.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

While these constraints present the `tableView` as I would expect, now the navigation bar always uses large title. I would like to mimic the behavior of the `UITableViewController`, so that when the `tableView` is scrolled to top, the large title is presented, otherwise the title collapses into the normal one.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed another aspect of `prefersLargeTitle` behavior that in some cases might provide even a simpler and more elegant solution. In my case, the `viewController` contained not only the `tableView` (otherwise I would simply use `UITableViewController` and I would get standard `prefersLargeTitle` behavior out-of-the-box), but also some other views. Now I noticed, that if you add the `tableView` as a first subview of the `viewController.view`, the table will control the large title feature:

```
// this will work
fileprivate func setupInitialHierarchy() {
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    self.view.addSubview(logoffButton)
}
```

Before I was creating the view hierarchy as follows:

```
// for some reason now the tableView will not control the large title
fileprivate func setupInitialHierarchy() {
    self.view.addSubview(logoffButton)
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
}
```

So it seems that if the `tableView` is the first subview of the `viewController`s `view`, we get the standard large titles behavior.

**Alternative solution**

However, if this is not possible, I have been able to simulate the standard behavior programmatically this way:

Implementing the delegate method for the `tableView` that reacts to scrolling, and then running the code that uses current `contentOffset` to either show, or hide the large title (`UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, so the `scrollView` parameter refers in this case to the `tableView`):

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0 {
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
    } else {
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    }
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Just remember that `scrollViewDidScroll` gets called repeatedly, so some `guard` there might be desirable.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Order matters since iOS 7 when automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets was initially introduced. So in order that flag to work with custom hierarchies of subviews it requires UIScrollView(or subclasses to be the root view). So I suppose the same is here.