# How to turn off adjusting large titles by UITableView in iOS 11?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios11

There's this large titles feature in iOS 11 that shows large title when the `UITableViewController`'s table is scrolled to top, and gets collapsed to standard small title when the user scrolls the table away from top. This is standard behavior. I need the navigation controller to behave a bit differently - I need to always show the large title. How to achieve this?

Following code does not help, it still collapses when scrolled.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've achieved it unintentionally when embedded `UITableViewController` inside `UIViewController`.

I'm not sure whether it is an Apple's bug or intended behavior.

So stack is as simple as `UINavigationController` -> `UIViewController`(used as container) -> `UITableViewController`

Here is **sample** of view controller with embedded `UITableViewController` fullscreen

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var vc = UITableViewController(style: .plain)
    var array: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(vc.view)
        view.addConstraint(view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.leadingAnchor))
        view.addConstraint(view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.rightAnchor))
        view.addConstraint(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.topAnchor))
        view.addConstraint(view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.bottomAnchor))

        vc.tableView.delegate = self
        vc.tableView.dataSource = self

        array = "0123456789".characters.map(String.init)
        vc.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "identifier")

        title = "Title"
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

*Here is the **result***

[image]

Hope it helps.

**P.S.** Surprisingly, my current problem is that I don't know how to get collapsing behavior with such architecture :)

Comment: I can help you with that, check this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178893/how-to-mimic-uitableviewcontroller-showing-of-the-large-titles-in-navigationb

Comment: but that's weird, in my code I have already embedded `UITableViewController` into the top `UIViewController`. I'm gonna try to do line by line diff with your code to find if there is something obscure there

Comment: @MilanNosáľ So, actually the post you've linked, is with answer to your problem. At least it's very similar to what you want. And thanks for the answer on my question, I'll give it a try.

Comment: sounds like it is, but it wasn't working.. it's like super weird behavior. In the end the embedding worked, I just had to use `UIViewController` with a `tableView` instead of `UITableViewController` (maybe it's `UITableViewController` that causes this behavior)..

Comment: moreover, I am adding some other views along with the tableView to the main view of my top `viewController`. one weird think that might shed a bit light on this is, that if I first add the `tableView` as a subview, and the other views, the `tableView` still controls the large title. However, when I first add other views, and only then the `tableView`, then it behaves as I expect. So the order of `UIView`s added to the top `viewController` matters.

Comment: please let me know if the other question/answer helped you

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to add another view between navigationBar and TableView with a height of 1.

```
let tableViewSeperator: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    // remove the color, so it wont be visible.
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue 
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
 }()
```

**One thing which is important is *add this seperator view as a subview of your viewcontroller's view before tableView*, otherwise it won't work**

```
view.addSubview(tableViewSeperator)
view.addSubview(tableView)
```

or if you want to save one line of code, you can also do it like this.

```
[tableViewSeperator, tableView].forEach({view.addSubview($0)})
```

Then set its constraints like this.

```
tableViewSeperator.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
tableViewSeperator.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true        
tableViewSeperator.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
tableViewSeperator.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
```

The last thing is change the tableView TopAnchor to be the BottomAnchor of sperator View.

```
tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewSeperator.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: createItemBtn.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Now when you scroll the the NavigationBar will stay as Large.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add UIView(it's can be width=0, height=0) before add UITableView.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX9Cx.png)

Then this code will work

```swift
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```