# UINavigationBar prefersLargeTitles = true, .navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always Ignored when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uinavigationbar

I have created a very basic `UITableViewController` within a `UINavigationController` and I want to keep the title large even when scrolling.
In the nav controller, I have set the nav bar `.prefersLargeTitles = true` and in the table view controller, I have set the `navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always`.

It starts off exactly as I want it:
[image]

But as I scroll up, the title goes to the top next to my bar items and shrinks:
[image]

I want to keep the title large.

EDIT: I have tried embedding the `UITableViewController` as a container view inside a `UIViewController` and that didn't change anything. I have also tried using a `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController` and that also didn't change anything.

EDIT2: I have created a test project to show the 3 options and how they don't work as expected:
https://github.com/fwaddle/TestNavBarScrolling/

EDIT3: The test project now includes the below suggestion to add a 0 width, 0 height `UIView` above the `UITableView`, but this removes the bounce and scaling of the title text. Also worth mentioning is that the initial `UITableViewController` in the test project actually works as I want it. The child UITableViewControllers do not work though. The only difference is that the initial one is a static `UITableViewController`. At this stage, I think this is a UIKit bug so I have filed a Feedback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn off adjusting large titles by UITableView in iOS 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46506401/how-to-turn-off-adjusting-large-titles-by-uitableview-in-ios-11)

Comment: Thanks @oneshot but I just tried doing that and it doesn't work. Thanks for the link - I hadn't seen that link before.

Answer (score 0):

It's default behaviour in iOS. If you want to want to overcome this behaviour, just add an dummy view (with 0 width and 0 height) above tableview.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I have a couple of problems with this, in that I will lose the nav bar expand animation with the text growing and bouncing back that users have come to expect. Also this seems like a solution that wont work in future versions of iOS. This might however be the only solution I have left otherwise, I will just have to remove the title altogether...