# App with Large Titles jittering on scroll

Tags: ios, swift

I know this is very vague, as I don't know what has caused this bug and it has seemingly popped up at random.

The problem is, when large titles are on, and there is scrollable content in the view, when I scroll down the large title becomes small, not only do I not like this behaviour, it's very jarring.

Here's a gif of the problem:
https://gyazo.com/8cadef763afeb535ca991c5ba8d7b249

As you can see as I scroll, the cell moves faster than I am scrolling.

I know it's hard to see where the large title begins, it begins where I go back and forth with my mouse horizontally

I have tried:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

Has anyone encountered this bug? How did you fix it?

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem? Looks fine to me... Maybe it's me & I just can't see it, ha.

Comment: The problem is when I scroll I want the large title to stay. At the moment it goes away when I scroll, which is a problem because it's very jittery, I scroll a little and it moves a lot

Comment: @LinusGeffarth https://gyazo.com/fe00630394301b5f2800d65f2046768d This shows it better, notice how I grab right on the line but it jumps around?

Comment: Ohh okay, you don't like that? I'm guessing it's implemented on purpose so the scroll view doesn't show half a title label. It's the same with search bars all across iOS. Makes sense to me. Also, UX-wise, I'd like to see that in your app :)

Comment: It didn't use to do that, it's quite a weird behaviour

Comment: I find it intuitive. Check out the notes app for instance. Open a note and notice how at the very top of that note there's the time stamp. Then try to position the scroll view so that only half of the label is shown...see? can't. Guess you'll have to live with that.

Comment: the difference is, this never used to happen, and in the notes app it is smooth, in mine it isn't

Comment: @Will check my question, seems it is very similar to what I was trying: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46506401/how-to-turn-off-adjusting-large-titles-by-uitableview-in-ios-11 . If it helps, please leave an upvote for both the question and answer. And for further information, check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178893/how-to-mimic-uitableviewcontroller-showing-of-the-large-titles-in-navigationb . It seems that if you dont put the scrollable view as the topmost subview of `UIViewController.view`, adjusting of the large titles won't work (and that's what you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys I solved it.

Firstly, yes, this *is* expected behaviour (unfortunately), however if you do not want it there is a solution.

The reason this happens if the only thing on the page is a scrollable view. Therefore to counteract this, you can use a button, or label, with no text (hence invisible).

If you use a *hidden* label or button or anything that cannot be scrolled on, the big nav bar will stay there.