# Does prefersLargeTitles work with UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios11

The standard use case of `UINavigationBar.prefersLargeTitles` is with a `UITableViewController`, or with a `UIViewController` that has a `TableView` as its first view in the hierarchy.

My question is, how to make `prefersLargetTitles` work with `UIPageViewController` that contains `TableViewControllers`?

Comment: take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178893/how-to-mimic-uitableviewcontroller-showing-of-the-large-titles-in-navigationb/46521937#46521937

Comment: Do you think it's possible that I create a `UIScrollView`, and puts the view of the `UIPageViewController` inside?

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I think the important thing is to let the `UINavigationController` find a `TableView` or `UIScrollView` for `prefersLargeTitles` to work "automatically".

Comment: that is the important thing - but I know of no such way.. only way it worked for me was to have the scrollView/tableView the first subview of viewControllers view - but now that is the pageViewController.view

Comment: `UITableView` is a `UIScrollView` subclass.. I would just try to work with that.. or you can simulate the pageviewcontroller by implementing pangesture recognizer - but that seems a bit overkill if you can hack it

Comment: @MilanNosáľ In my case, I have some `UITableViewControllers` inside a `UIPageViewController`, so your solution that makes use of `scrollViewDidScroll` seem straightforward for me. How close was your 'simulation' of the standard `prefresLargeTitles` behaviour?

Comment: Close enough for me.. just set up a delegate to manipulate that navigation item, and you'll see

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Thanks. I will give that a try:)

Comment: if it will work, please leave an upvote on the original question/answer